# Emacs: Makefile tab size

Tags: emacs

How to make tab to indent by 4 spaces (be it spaces or true tabs like in makefiles). By default my emacs inserts 2 spaces in C files and tabs indent by 8 in makefiles.

Thanks.

Comment: You want true tabs in Makefiles, where the (rather subtle) difference between spaces and tabs is syntactically relevant.

Comment: Yes, I want true tabs in makefiles. But I don't want them to be as wide as 8 spaces. That wastes too much real estate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this in my emacs config file to set tab width to 4 globally:

```
; Turn on tabs                                                                                                       
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)                                                                                             
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)                                                                                     

;; Bind the TAB key                                                                                                   
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command)                                                                     

;; Set the tab width                                                                                                  
(setq default-tab-width 4)                                                                                            
(setq tab-width 4)                                                                                                    
(setq c-basic-indent 4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this for the last hour!

Comment: It should be (setq-default tab-width 4) instead of (setq default-tab-width 4). I tried to edit the answer but the edit queue is always full.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Changing-the-length-of-a-Tab.html